# Between the north and south poles of a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

[image]For context, I'm taking 11th-grade physics,

my teacher repeatedly told us that you cannot separate the south and north poles of a magnet, however, when shown for example an AC electric generator the conductor is in the magnetic field and between the north and south poles of the magnet, how's this possible when you cannot even separate them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: define "Separate".

Answer (score 2):

It seems you misunderstood the drawing.
The magnets in the drawing are *not* meant to have only
one pole each (the left magnet having a north pole only,
and the right magnet having a south pole only).
Instead these magnets have a north *and* a south pole,
like every magnet has.
So a better drawing would look like this.

[image]

So the statement, that magnets always have north and south
pole, is still valid.
Of course this does not change the elecromagnetic
induction in the wire moving through the magnetic field
between the north and south poles.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher's words may have been a bit imprecise.  It's true that you cannot take a permanent magnet and cut it into North and South pole halves. Each smaller magnet will have a North and South pole.

But the actual physical law is that the magnetic field lines never originate from a source or terminate in a sink. They either form closed loops or extend to infinity. See below for some examples of magnetic field lines in various configurations, including the one you mentioned.

[image]

This principle is known as Gauss's Law for Magnetism:

$$  \mathop{\vcenter{
   \huge\unicode{x222F}\,
  }}_{S} \mathbf{B} \cdot \text d\mathbf{A} = 0         $$

Which says that the flux of a magnetic field $\textbf{B}$ through any closed surface is zero. In plain English, this means that if you draw an imaginary closed shape like a sphere or a cube, the number of magnetic field lines entering the shape and the number exiting is always the same. The magnetic field lines do not "start" or "end" anywhere.

This is in contrast to electric field lines, which can start at positive charges and end at negative charges:

[image]

These are governed by Gauss's Law for Eletrostatics:

$$  \mathop{\vcenter{
   \huge\unicode{x222F}\,
  }}_{S} \mathbf{E} \cdot \text d\mathbf{A} = 4\pi Q        $$

This states that the total flux of the electric field $\textbf{E}$ through a closed surface is equal to $4\pi Q$ where $Q$ is the amount of electric charge enclosed by the surface. This law means that for the electric field, if you count up the number of field lines entering and exiting your imaginary sphere: if the number exiting is greater, your sphere encloses a positive charge; if the number entering is greater, it encloses a negative charge; if it is zero, it encloses no charge.

So the Law for Magnetism is that, unlike positive and negative electric charges, magnetic "charges" or Monopoles (e.g. an object that is just North, or just South) do not exist.

In closing, here is an excellent video that illustrates these concepts
[Video](https://youtu.be/gvX29HPmBEI)

Images

1. Open source from Wikipedia
2. Credit:
   https://www.toppr.com/ask/content/concept/electric-field-lines-248765/

Answer (score 0):

All depends how you create magnetic field. Firstly, you can imagine that there are two magnets, one on the left another on the right, so you have south and north as in figure, and each magnet has south and north. Secondly, you can create magnetic field by a  coil, thus you do not need a south or a north in this sense. Magnetic field is created by an electronic current

Comment: Also , magnetic north and south is not like charges where you can separate electrons and protons. It is dipole  moment that you cannot separate.

Answer (score 0):

This question hinges on the meaning of 'separate'. The poles of a magnet are near opposite ends of a magnet, so in that sense they are already separate. I think that what your teacher means is that you can't take away one pole of a magnet, leaving the other in place. For example, if you cut a magnet in half midway between its poles, each half is found to have both a North and a South pole.

This all makes sense if you model a magnet as aligned loops carrying currents in the same sense. Magnetic field lines generated by the currents pass through the loops and emerge from near the geometric end of the magnet that we call the North end. They pass through the space around the magnet, and re-enter the magnet near the end that we call the 'South' end. Thus the field lines are continuous closed loops. This will still be the case for each half of a magnet cut in half.